# Objective-C DOM XML parser for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, dom

Hello guys I'm looking for a way on the iPhone to parse an XML document using DOM. I have been using SAX with NSXMLParser but now I really want a DOM tree (or anything that can **quickly** translate the XML document into an NSDictionary)
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, `NSXMLDocument` (which does what you're asking) does not exist on the iPhone.  You may have to roll your own parser using `libxml2`, or try something like [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML/) or [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML).

Comment: TouchXML doesn't support ARC. KissXML supports ARC.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `libxml2` with an Objective-C front without SAX events, take a look at this useful set of [wrapper functions](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html).

You issue an XPath query to your XML document object and get back Foundation class objects: `NSArray`, `NSString`, and `NSDictionary`, e.g.:

```
NSArray *queriedBuckets = PerformXMLXPathQuery(responseData, @"//*[local-name()='Buckets']/*[local-name()='Bucket']");
```

These functions help merge the speed of `libxml2` with the readability and usability of Objective-C code.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at the Google Data API for Objective-C (iPhone) at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

In particular, look at these files which define the GDataXMLNode class:

http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/