# need a simple example for libxml2 DOM way parsing on iOS

Tags: ios, dom, libxml2, sample

I'm learning how to use libxml2 from Apple's sample XMLPerformance project but it's for the SAX model of parsing.

Can anyone provide a sample of libxml2 DOM parsing? Many thanks.

Comment: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html

Answer (score 2):

look at this website for different parsers. It does contain few DOM parsers.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Comment: You will have to write your own or you can use any of those given the above mentioned link. However look at this post for some useful wrapper functions http://stackoverflow.com/a/1496199/641062

Comment: **thank you, seems GData DOM Parser you mentioned is a good choice**

Comment: Welcome. Glad to be of some help.